# What command to use so that no question number appears at start of the question?

Tags: macros, pdftex, questionnaire

I am making a survey form. I am using template from [Creating questionnaires with LaTeX](http://www.svenhartenstein.de/creating-questionnaires-with-latex/). I want to make a question so that a question number doesn't comes up at the start of a question. When I use `\Qitem` command, question number appears against that line.

Please guide me how can I avoid a question numbers.

```
\newcounter{itemnummer}
\newcommand{\Qitem}[2][]{% #1 optional, #2 notwendig
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\stepcounter{itemnummer}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{a}}{\stepcounter{itemnummer}}{}
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=2pt,leftmargin=2.8em]
\item[\textbf{\arabic{itemnummer}#1.}] #2
\end{enumerate}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. In this cae since you do not know how to write your macro your should give clear examples of the types of input and output you want. This certainly is not clear to me from what you have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command doesn't show a consecutive number (and also doesn't step the counter), but still has an optional argument if you want to label your question.

```
\newcommand{\myQitem}[2][]%
 {\begin{enumerate}[topsep=2pt,leftmargin=2.8em]
  \item[\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\textbf{#1.}}] #2
  \end{enumerate}
 }
```

After this definition, the questions

```
\myQitem{To be or not to be?}
\myQitem[1]{Two beers or not two beers?}
```

will result in

[image]

Comment: You sir are awesome. Thank you so much for the solution.